# Laravel Eloquent alias table

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have 3 tables:

```
professor | id | name  

discipline | id | name
```

and one to link them

```
disc_prof | prof_id | disc_id
```

How do I retrieve data as an `Inner Join`  ?

Is it something like:

```
SELECT prof.name, prof.id, disc.id, disc.name 
FROM disc_prof AS dc INNER JOIN professor as prof ON prof.id = dc.prof_id
INNER JOIN discipline AS disc ON  dc.disc_id = disc.id
```

What I did so far:

#### Professor Model

```
class Professor extends Model
{
    protected $table = "professor";

    public function disc()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Discipline');
    }
}
```

#### Discipline Model

```
class Disciplina extends Model
{
    protected $table = "discipline";
}
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'database.discipline_professor' doesn't exist
```

It's not `database.discipline_professor`, it's `database.disc_prof`.
What is the correct way to change it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So Eloquent automatically builds your table names for pivots. It takes the relationship table names, in this case `professor` and `discipline`, arranges them in alphabetical order, and makes each word singular. That's where `discipline_professor` comes from. A pivot table for `users` and `regions` would be `region_user`, as another example. The two IDs for the table are then taken from the relationship name and the table name, so it would expect `professor_id` and `discipline_id`.

You can get around that when you create the relationship. If you look at the [docs](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_belongsToMany) for `Model::belongsToMany()`, you will see the arguments are:

```
string $related, string $table = null, string $foreignKey = null, string $otherKey = null, string $relation = null
```

So you need to set `$table`, `$foreignKey`, and `$otherKey`. In your case:

```
class Professor extends Model
{
    protected $table = "professor";

    public function disc()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Discipline', 'disc_prof', 'prof_id', 'disc_id');
    }
}
```

As a sidenote, I *highly* suggest using the recommended names with Eloquent. All tables should be plural, all pivots should match what I stated above, all foreign keys should be the relationship name in singular form + `_id`, etc. It will make working with Eloquent much, much easier and faster. You can find some of the details of what Eloquent expects in their [Relationships](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships) documentation. There is no clear cut list of expectations from what I have been able to find, so that will have to do.

Comment: You Rock, Josh ! Thanks a bunch. I'm really noob with Larave. I'll do as you suggested and rename the database as it's just a teste. Really thanks for your help and links you provided.

Comment: Yeah, no problem @PlayHardGoPro. If you're just starting with Laravel, I suggest reading through the docs (which are mediocre but improving) and watching the "Laravel 5 Fundamentals" series from Laracasts, which will be a great help. Jeffrey Way's Laracast material is very straight forward and very easy to learn.

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro I was just digging through some of the docs for my own stuff and came across a section that explains some of the naming conventions. This is part of what I tried to find this morning and was unable to http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions

Comment: Thanks again man ! Really appreciate your consideration and help. You're the best !